# Verify if the function $\, f\colon \Bbb Z \to \Bbb R $ defined by $\, f(n)=n^3-3n$ is injective

Tags: real-analysis, functions

I am stuck on the following problem :

I have to verify whether the following two statements are true/false?

> 1. The function $\, f\colon \Bbb Z \to \Bbb R $ defined by $\, f(n)=n^3-3n$ is injective
> 2. The polynomial $\,x^3+3x-2\pi\,$ is irreducible over $\Bbb R$

*My Attempt*: For 1, I see that for $x \neq y \,\text{where}\, x,y \in \Bbb Z$, $f(x) \neq f(y)$. Or, in a different way, if I take $$\begin{align} f(x)=f(y) \implies x^3-3x=y^3-3y \implies .......\implies (x-y)(x^2+y^2+xy-3)=0 \implies x=y ,\,\,\text{by taking}\,\,x^2+y^2+xy-3 \neq 0 \end{align}$$.

So, option 1 is true.

For option 2, $\,x^3+3x-2\pi = \frac17(7x^3+21x-44)\,$ . Now,I am not sure which way to go.

Can someone explain? Thanks and regards to all.

Comment: You'd better re-check option 1.

Comment: And for option 2, $\pi \neq 22/7$. Hint: use use the fact that a polynomial of degree $\leq 3$ is reducible if and only if it has a root.

Comment: What do you mean "by taking $\ldots\ne0$"?

Comment: $(-1)^3-3(-1)=2=(2)^3-3(2)$, but $-1 \neq 2$.

Comment: @Magdiragdag still I could not follow the hints. How should I tackle with $\pi$ ? Could you explain further..

Comment: @J.W.Perry thanks a lot sir, for the counter example...

Comment: Just show that the polynomial has a root by using the intermediate value theorem; you don't need to know what that root actually is.

Comment: So, as we see that $f(0)<0$ and $f(10)>0\,\,$say for example. So,it has a root in between $0\,\,\text{and}\,\,10$ . Am I right?

Comment: For part 1. you can't just say $x^2+y^2+xy-3 \neq 0$ because that's not always true. Using the quadratic formula you get $x = \frac{-y \pm \sqrt{12-3y^2}}{2}$ which will have a solution for $y^2 \neq 12$. And for this solution $x\neq y$ necessarily. So there is more than one value for x, meaning the function isn't injective. (For a proof though all you would need is a counterexample like J.W. Perry provided).

Comment: @andraiamatrix thanks a lot sir. Got your point.

Comment: @learner Yes on your comment. $f(0)<0<f(10)$ hence there exists a $c \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(c)=0$. Therefore $(x-c)$ is a factor.

Comment: @J.W.Perry thanks a lot for the verification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Combining the above discussions in the comments,I can see that  for the first question,the given function is not injective .

**Counter example** : $(−1)^3−3(−1)=2=(2)^3−3(2), \text{but}\, −1≠2. $

For the 2nd question, use the following hints:

**hint 1** : use the fact that a polynomial of degree $≤3$ is reducible if and only if it has a root.

**hint 2** : Just show that the polynomial has a root by using the intermediate value theorem; you don't need to know what that root actually is.